# window.opener is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a webpage that opens up a popup child window by clicking an image on the parent window.

And I would like to pass the value from the child window's text box to the parent window's text box.

I have found a tutorial on this topic and followed his method.
http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/window-child3-demo.php
However it didn't work for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myImg").click(function(){   
    var win1=window.open("popupWindows/p1.html","myWindow"," top=500, left=500, width=500,height=500");
    });
});
```

^ This opens up the child window.

```
function childWindowFunction()
{
opener.document.getElementById("parentTextBox").value=document.getElementById("userInput").value;
//alert(document.getElementById("userInput").value); <-- this works
//alert(opener.document.getElementById("parentTextBox").value); <-- not working at all
close();
}
```

^ This executes from the child window.

And here is the executable code.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/83hwyhbz7u4nuie/sandbox.7z

I guess the `opener.document.getElementById("parentTextBox").value` is not working. Can someone tell me what's wrong? Thank you!

---

Ignore the code above. I have created a jsfiddle for this. jsfiddle.net/yuyhero/6FKVM/1

I would like to use button inside the popup window to do the task instead of using the get value button from the parent window.

Now that the button inside the popup window does not work at all.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you inspected `opener` and `opener.document` and what does `opener.document.getElementById("parentTextBox")` return?

Comment: @TarunPai when you open a new window - `opener` is the window that open ed that window

Comment: I followed the instructions of a tutorial where function post_value(){
opener.document.f1.p_name.value = document.frm.c_name.value;
self.close();
} can pass the value of the child window to the parent window. The tutorial URL: http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/window-child3.php

Comment: @James_ can you host your code on jsfiddle?

Comment: @James_ I don't see any `opener` related code in the `Sandbox.7z` file. Also, make sure you aren't missing any file references.

Comment: The opener seems flawed. I ran the example on that demo site.. it worked only once.. then I changed value and opened another window it had my old value. As a matter of fact it never had my old value it always gives the value `test` lol atleast on Chrome it does. Plus that tutorial seems like it's from the 1990's.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/yuyhero/6FKVM/1/ I would like to use button inside the popup window to do the task instead of using the get value button from the parent window.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine for a moment that you use window.open to create "myWindow" and then from within "myWindow" you use window.open to create "windowTheSequel".

You now have two "openers", e.g. the original browser window and "myWindow". Therefore, opener wouldn't know which window to reference without the child (myWindow) as a reference.

So begin the line with `myWindow.opener...` and you should be good to go.