# Chrome javascript error cannot read property 'opener' of null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a bit of javascript that I use to determine where an 'opener' window is (generally to work out which monitor a user is using and to open pop up windows on the monitor they are using.

```
if (typeof (window.opener) != "undefined")
{
    var x_win = window.self;
    while (x_win != "undefined")
    {
        x_win = x_win.opener;
        if (typeof (x_win.opener) == "undefined") //chrome falls over here
        {
            winX = (document.all) ? x_win.screenLeft : x_win.screenX;
            break;
         }
     }
}
```

The above works perfectly in IE but Chrome falls over on the line marked in the code with 'chrome falls over here'. It reports: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opener' of null.

I am testing for "undefined" - what do I need to do to get this to work in Chrome?

Comment: Note that `typeof` is an operator, not a function, no need to put its operand in parentheses.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374700/window-opener-is-not-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.opener | not working in chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671218/window-opener-not-working-in-chrome)

Comment: you are assigning `var x_win = window.opener;` it is returning null i guess. and you should check for `while (typeof x_win != "undefined")` not `typeof (x_win.opener) == "undefined"`

Comment: What seems to be going wrong is that Chrome is ignoring the first line ... if (typeof (window.opener) != "undefined"). In the situation I am testing, there is no window.opener - it thinks it is null not 'undefined'. Does Chrome return null instead of undefined if it cannot find an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `typeof`:

```
while (typeof x_win != "undefined")
// ----^
```

Separately, though, I'd do a truthiness check on `x_win` rather than a `typeof` check, since I'd expect `opener` to be `null` rather than `undefined` if not set:

```
while (x_win)
```

---

Note that if the goal is to find the last window in a chain that doesn't have an `opener`, you can make it *much* shorter:

```
var x_win = window;
while (x_win.opener) {
    x_win = x_win.opener;
}
winX = document.all ? x_win.screenLeft : x_win.screenX;
```

There's a slight difference there, in that we get `winX` even if the current window has no `opener`, whereas in your code you're not assigning to it in that case, but I'm assuming that's useful. If not, just put `if (window.opener)` at the top.